# Application developed for WIN CE Emulator 5.0 does not work on WIN CE Device 6.0?

Tags: c++, windows-mobile, windows-ce, emulation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why simple console app runs but dialog based does not run in WIN CE 6.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10959134/why-simple-console-app-runs-but-dialog-based-does-not-run-in-win-ce-6-0)

I am developing an application in embedded VC++ 4. When I choose WIN CE emulator 5.0 as platform, it runs on it correctly. But when I copy that generate file for emulator to real device having WIN CE 6.0 it does not work.

Why? And what should I do?

Thanks,

Comment: Provide some more details - are you getting an error when it runs? Does it not load at all? Invalid EXE? EVC4 Compilers are full of bugs; if this is an important project, your best bet is to use Visual Studio 2008 (or at least VS2005).

Comment: does not run at all with no message

Comment: I saw a similar problem with an App I was writing, but I forgot what the issue was. If you can't run it in the debugger on the target system, then I would add some messagebox's to display progress during initialization. This is how I solved the issue.

Comment: In some platforms I get message Invalid EXE.

Comment: The CPU type may be preventing you from running your EXE on all platforms. WinCE supports ARM (more than 1 flavor), MIPS, X86, SH3, SH4. If the CPU type matches and the target OS version is lower or equal to what you're running it on then it will execute.

Comment: I tested all Arm, MIPS, X86, SH3, SH4. In  some cases it does not run at all and some cases I get message Invalid EXE

Comment: It sounds like you need to debug the problem. It could be a bug in the compiler since you're using EVC4. The compiler quality in order from worst to best: MIPS, SH3/SH4, ARM, X86.

Comment: We need some dll files. I found the solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10965480/779408).

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that when you build for the emulator in Win CE 5.0, you're building for an x86 instruction set. Depending on the device, you'll probably have to compile for an ARM instruction set.

Basically, you'll also need the actual SDKs for the device you want to ship your software for. However, there is no standard windows CE 6.0 SDK. Instead, device manufactures create them with the Windows Platform Builder tool. You'll have to find out where you can get the SDK for your device and compile for that platform.